# Remove specific string from file

Tags: linux, grep, awk, egrep

output.txt

```
1.1.1.1:22/ does not support password authentication. [ERROR] target ssh://2.2.2.2:22/ does not support password authentication. [ERROR] target ssh://3.3.3.3
```

i want to remove string `:22/ does not support password authentication. [ERROR] target ssh://` from `output.txt` and to put IP addresses in new file

**Desired output:**

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

I tried with

```
cat output.txt | grep -vE "(:22/ does not support password authentication. [ERROR] target ssh://)
```

and

```
cat output.txt | egrep -v ":22/ does not support password authentication. [ERROR] target ssh://"
```

and  `cat output.txt | grep -v ":22/ does not support password authentication. [ERROR] target ssh://"`
but above 3 commands do not remove nothing.
Tried with awk - same results:

```
 awk '{gsub(":22/ does not support password authentication. [ERROR] target ssh://","");print}' output.txt
```

I didn't try `sed` because my string contains escape characters

Comment: Is that the whole output or just partial? That is, does it always come in weirdly truncated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a perl one-liner that does the job:

```
perl -ape 's/.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})/$1\n/g' file.txt 
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/              # substitute    
    .*?             # 0 or more any character but newline
    (               # start group 1
        \d+         # 1 or more digits
        (?:         # start non capture group
            \.      # a dot
            \d+     # 1 or more digits
        ){3}        # end group, must appear 3 times
    )               # end group 1
/               # with
    $1\n            # content of group 1 (i.e. the IP), followed by linefeed
/g              # global
```

If you want to match only IP addresses, you have to replace all the occurrences of `\d+` in the above regex with:

```
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]\d?\d?)
```

that gives:

```
s/.*?((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]\d?\d?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]\d?\d?)){3})/$1\n/g
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is the right way to remove an arbitrary string. In a general case you need to deal with the syntax, escape characters etc.

`grep` finds lines with or without matches. It cannot remove strings easily. With `-o` it can show you matching *fragments* of lines. This is useful if you can build a regex for what you need to keep, not for what you need to remove. (Your `grep` may or may not support `-o`; the option is not required by POSIX.)

In case of your example such regex exists. The command will be:

```
<output.txt grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+'
```

The regex matches exactly four sequences of digits separated with literal dots. A sequence of digits must contain at least 1 digit, so `...` will not match; but `999.888.12345678.0` will match. If this is a problem then you should build a better regex or choose a different approach (which may work by actually removing the undesired string as you originally wanted).

Comment: In fact, i ended up using multiple sed commands to get what i want. Thanks